Blazor with identity framework. Server or webassembly?
I have small application to write. I need custom view user managment, scheduler and file hosting in my app.
I want to work with identity mechanism with roles.
My problem is that I don't know which version of blazor choose? Server, webassembly or new App?
I can't find clear response about which of these work best with identy framework from .net.
Thanks.

I started with Blazor Server NET6 and just converted to Blazor Web App NET8. I would go with the Web App simply because it separates the server from the client way better than the Server App did. I also like the auto rendering feature in which you can combine both server side rendering and client side rendering into your project.

Both of them work with identity framework. Server is easier to develop since you don't hassle with api and dtos. I would reccomend : go with Blazor Web App, local interactivity. Do server interactivity if needed, if it doesn't suits your users, try wasm, also doesn't suits your needs? Try pre-rendering and Auto modes.

Thank you for your answer. Do you have any experience with identity in web app?

@Alamakanambra I was try implement identity mechanism to server .net 7 but this produce a lot of problems because I can't login user by usermenager in razor page.

Blazor Web App(new app) Server render mode is best for your needs. Just choose the "individual" authentication and you will get a template with .NET identity mechanism to start.

Webassembly rendermode will be much harder because it may involve rendermodes switching.
The Blazor Server App template is not available since .Net8. So I will not recommend.

OK, thank you for your answer.
Yes I was started create my map in server app in .net 7 but i have a lot of problems with cookie, user identity. Old server app require a lot of custom middleware to use identity mechanism and at the end I have problems with it in azure service app.
Thanks all.
